# Cosmic web distribution and neuron system similarities

Tags: cosmology, biology, structure-formation

Does the cosmic web follow Gaussian distribution? If so, is that the reason it resembles the human neuron system? Does the human neuron system follow Gaussian distribution too?

(sorry if this deviates from physics a bit)

Comment: Even if both did, would you reach any conclusion from that?

Comment: Yes, it would prove that the shape is a common Gaussian distribution pattern

Comment: That would not be a conlcusion. A conclusion would be "given the similar distributions then the filaments might be sentient like the brain", or something like that.

Comment: It is a conclusion to me and also it would not make sense for the cosmic web to be sentient, because that would be 99.99999999 percent impossible.

Comment: I am glad you think that way, For some reason the question looked to me wanting to go into that direction.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that confusion.

Comment: So, would it be a relic (like calcium deposits in the earth's crust, or maybe "on the earth's crust" as they would've more commonly lain at the time of their origin), as a continuous normal probability system is described in Wikipedia, or would the temporal gap between their appearance then and their appearance now provide some wiggle room for sentience of a previous actor,  just as some relics of a transition between life and death might appear to be, to beings arriving on their onetime scene later?

Comment: I mean, I'm an agnostic, but "biology" in a physics context is (I'm a little surprised to find) an extant PSE tag, and I doubt that anyone knows enough chemistry (yet) to rule out the biology/physics meld that the OP seems to be driving at.  As this ex-bus driver would say, "There's always room for one more", whether it's a 9 or a nein.